# Swapping and recomputing giving different results

Tags: c++, swap

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but two versions of code that should give the same results are giving different results. If anyone could explain what is going on, I would really appreciate it.

The situation is as follows. I am working with arrays as 'vectors' and I have a simple function `sub` with two overloads to calculate the difference between the two vectors. The first basically calculates `v := v - w`, while the second calculates `x := v - w`.

```
// Subtract w[] from v[]
template <class T>
void sub(T *v, T *w, short m)
{
    for (short r = 0; r < m; r++)
        v[r] = v[r] - w[r];
}

// Subtract w[] from v[] and store result in x[]
template <class T>
void sub(T *v, T *w, T *x, short m)
{
    for (short r = 0; r < m; r++)
        x[r] = v[r] - w[r];
}
```

Now at some point I need to calculate `v - w`, and if it satisfies some condition, replace `v` by `v - w`. If not, `v` should remain unchanged. At first I had

```
...
// temp := v - w
sub<T>(v, w, temp, m);
if (condition on temp)
{
    // v := v - w
    sub<T>(v, w, m);
}
...
```

To improve efficiency, I figured it would be a waste to calculate the same thing twice, so I replaced the above by

```
...
// temp := v - w
sub<T>(v, w, temp, m);
if (condition on temp)
{
    // swap v and temp
    std::swap(v, temp);
}
...
```

The variable `temp` is in fact reused after, which could cause problems, but every time I first call `sub<T>(v, w, temp, m);` (thus erasing all content in the array) before using `temp` again.

Now after doing the above replacement, the results of my algorithm suddenly change. If anyone could explain why the results change and what is happening, I would be very grateful!

Thanks in advance.

---

### Edit

A quick check shows that in both cases, in each iteration, the final value of `v` and the initial value of `temp` is the same. So the functions are doing what they are supposed to do...

The only possibility I can think of explaining the odd behavior is that for some reason, the function `std::swap` is using randomness, leading to different results. I'm using the same seed for each run and should get the same results each time, but if `std::swap` uses `rand()` somewhere, that would explain the different results. But I have no idea why this function would use `rand()`.

Comment: What is the typeof `temp`?  Do you allocate new memory for it, or is it pointing to one of the other already existing arrays?

Comment: Is it me, or have you just swapped two pointers, rather than their contents?

Comment: Why are you your `sub` arguments of type `T *` if you work with `vector<T>`? What is the exact type of `v`, `w` and `temp`?

Comment: @Irfy -- my understanding is that the OP is working with arrays, not `vector<>`'s

Comment: I'm working with arrays rather than `vector<>`'s. So initialization is done by e.g. `T *temp = new T[m]`. And T could be float, long double, ...

Comment: @TMM - a side comment: you do not need to specify `<T>` in your call `sub`, the compiler should be able to deduce the template argument in your case.

Comment: @Robinson - why is that a problem?  Besides that the swap is causing the problem -- but you would get the same behavior if you swapped the contents just as well

Comment: @TMM - Can you post input/original values for the arrays in question and also output showing the different behavior (the contents of all three arrays)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that at that point in the code, "the damage was already done". The swapping was done inside a function `bla`, which took `v` as an argument, as follows

```
void bla(..., T* v, ...)
{
    ...
    // temp := v - w
    sub<T>(v, w, temp, m);
    if (condition on temp)
    {
        // swap v and temp
        std::swap(v, w, m);
    }
    ...
}
```

But today I learned that this way, the function `bla` only makes a local *copy* of the pointer and works with that, instead of using the actual address with the actual pointer stored in the memory. So instead of swapping the global `v` with `temp`, I was swapping a local `v` with `temp`, and so this did not affect the global `v`. This also explains why I did not notice any problems locally, as inside the function, `v` indeed behaves the way it should. So at that point in the code, the only way to swap the values would be recomputing the expression.

A simple solution works: change the function declaration to `void bla(..., T*& v, ...)`, so that the local copy of `v` used in the function `bla` actually corresponds to the same physical memory address as the global `v`. Then `std::swap()` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you re-calculate `temp` as `v-w` every time you are about to use `temp`, the value will be different, when `v` is unchanged and when `v` points to the array previously pointed to by `temp`.

Consider this: in the first case, your calculation is : `temp=v-w` every time.  In the second case: `temp=v-w; swap(temp, v); temp=v-w;` -- the one after the swap is different from the one before as the array pointed to by `v` is now containing values from `temp-w` (using the values of pointers after the swap).  That is, the second assignment is equivalent to `temp=(v-w)-w;` using the original arrays

Comment: In the first case, inside the if-statement, I call the other overload of `sub` that calculates `v := v' = v - w`. So shouldn't I then also get `temp := v' - w = (v - w) - w` in the second iteration?

Comment: No, unless tou recalculate `temp` in the first case all the time as well -- I was under the impression, you only did that in the second case